# Timestamp where clause that is not working

Tags: postgresql

My query is to return all the records between two timestamp date and times.

This is being used for 30 minute intervals in time. My query example that is failing should return 27 rows of data between `2/1/2019 1:30:00` and `2/1/2019 01:59:00` returns 14582 rows with the date ranges from `2/1/2019 13:04:00` to `2/1/2019 01:59:00`.

I have tried using `<=` and `>=` for the ranges and have tried using between. I get the same number of records returned wither way.

```
select "ACD Login ID", "Start"
from prdintfeb where
"Start"::timestamp>=timestamp '2/1/219 01:30:00' and "Start"::timestamp <= timestamp '2/1/2019 01:59:00'
order by "Start"
```

Comment: I normally just use the `::timestamp` after the string containing the timestamp. `'2019-02-01 01:30:00'::timestamp`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and put the timestamp cast after the date time string and ran this query 'code' select "ACD Login ID", "Start","Sort Name","Label"
from prdintfeb where
"Start"::timestamp>='2019/2/1 00:00:00'::timestamp and "Start"::timestamp <= '2019/02/02 00:29:00'::timestamp
order by "Start" it returned 150573 records and should have returned 367

Comment: What data type is `Start` and how do the values look? I'm sure the database isn't lying (unless there is data corruption involved).

Comment: I am also interested in the data type of `"Start"`. Is it `text` or `varchar`? Example input would help a lot here. Here is a fiddle that is working with `timestamp` as `"Start"` data type.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c14JGGfnv74gL7QrJTbGHg/0

Comment: "Start" is a timestamp field

Comment: "Start" is a timestamp field and "ACD Login ID" is a text field.  the table has slightly over 3,700,000 records all with dates between 2/1/2019 and 2/28/2019.  I am trying to export the records rolled up to summaries on 30 min intervals Into Excel using VBA. Of course there are more fields in the table however the problem is reproduced with just these two in the query.

Comment: Manually looking at the records with the query adding order by "Start", "ACD Login ID" shows that the ID's are alphabetically listed in order by date such as a date of '2/1/2019' but then further down most of the ID's are listed multiple other times. It almost acts like it is sorting on the time portion not just the date. I added a date column and copied the dates from start over to it, and tried. It did the same thing.  I even tried adding a text column for the date and got the same behavior.  there are over 1200 employees each with a unique "ACD Login ID"